# How to make my entourage understand that I'm not a technical support

Tags: friends, family, acceptable-behavior

I'm a 20 years old programmer and everyday comes with this person asking me for help to configure his iCloud, fix his printer, remove a virus, and other tasks like that.

Yesterday my father comes ask me to help him transfer his data to his new phone. I was busy and I never done it before so I said that I don't know and that he should google it.
He responded that's not cool because I'm on computer all day so I better know how to do it than him.

This kind of sentence just makes me super angry.
How can I tell my family that I'll not help them for technical questions anymore ?

Comment: Hi Julien, welcome to IPS! is this [question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/9042/how-to-tell-people-im-not-their-tech-support) or this [question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/11415/how-to-deal-with-someone-who-ignores-your-lack-of-knowledge/) (which seem related, to me), of any help in your case?

Comment: Just to check - if your father is driving a car does your family go to a mechanics or your father fix everything? Same thing with washers, washing machines. Also check "arbitrary digital exclusion"